# Angular 9 : Error when upgrade to Angular 9 "9.0.0-rc.5"

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular9

I get an error when i upgrade my project from 8 to 9.
My project build and run serve with any error in the console of the terminal but in chrome when i go to http://localhost:4200, i get this following error in the console of chrome :

```
Error: Dependency array must have arguments.
at reflectDependency (core.js:17943)
at core.js:17916
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at convertDependencies (core.js:17912)
at reflectDependencies (core.js:17903)
at directiveMetadata (core.js:39767)
at getDirectiveMetadata (core.js:39711)
at Function.get (core.js:39688)
at getDirectiveDef (core.js:1855)
at addDirectiveDefToUndecoratedParents (core.js:39795)
```

my @ngModule of the project did not change just dependencies and i dont know why a dependency array is empty.

this is my actual package.json :

````
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^8.1.0-beta.0",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.900.0-rc.5",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.0-rc.5",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.900.0-rc.5",
    "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "~0.900.0-rc.5",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^9.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "9.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/cli": "9.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "9.0.0-rc.5",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^7.2.1",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "1.1.6",
    "@nrwl/schematics": "7.1.1",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.8",
    "@types/highlight.js": "^9.12.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.11",
    "@types/lunr": "^2.1.5",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.105",
    "@types/pdfjs-dist": "2.0.0",
    "@types/url-parse": "^1.1.0",
    "angular-cli-builders": "^2.1.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "commitizen": "^3.0.5",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "cz-customizable": "^5.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "^6.0.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-file": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-foreach": "^0.1.0",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.6.1",
    "highlight.js": "^9.12.0",
    "husky": "^1.3.1",
    "jasmine": "~2.99.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-marbles": "^0.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "karma": "~2.0.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-scss-preprocessor": "^3.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^8.1.0",
    "marked": "^0.4.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^9.0.0-rc.2",
    "ngx-speculoos": "^0.2.3",
    "node-minify": "^3.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "node-sass-tilde-importer": "^1.0.2",
    "optimist": "^0.6.1",
    "prettier": "^1.15.3",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "shallow-render": "7.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^22.4.5",
    "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
    "tsickle": ">=0.25.5",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "tslint": "^5.10.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4"
  },```

thanks in advance for your answers.
````

Comment: Why are you trying to update to Angular 9.0? Angular 8.0 only released at May 2019 and it's the stable version of Angular.

Comment: so preparing for angular 9 and it will be release the end of this month.

Comment: This error is thrown by the Angular injector when it can not resolve all of the parameters for a constructor. There is nothing we can do to help you with what you've shared. Check all of your injectables, and verify all of your third-party libraries are compatible with Angular 9.

Comment: thanks @Reactgular for your analyse and ur answer.

Answer (score 0):

run `npm audit` command and get existing conflicts after upgrading angular. may be some of the third party libraries may not compatible with latest angular. based on the out put of the above command you may get an idea .

Answer (score 0):

### Angular upgrade to 9.x

I have make a note for our project may be this will help you out. if you find any challenge feel free to ask will happy to help you out.

Follow below steps depends on your requirement may be few are required.

> For routing

```js
const routes: Routes = [
 { 
  path: 'lazy',
  loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule', // use this syntax for non-ivy or Angular 7 and below
loadChildren : () => import('./lazy/lazy.module').then(m => m.LazyModule)**, // new dynamic import method in angular 8 or above
  }
];
```

————————————————————————
Note:

> *Error TS1323: Dynamic import is only supported when '--module' flag is 'commonjs' or 'esNext'***

***Solution* above issue**

> You are using dynamic import so you have to change your tsconfig.json like this to target your code to esnext module**

```js
{
"compileOnSave":  false,
"compilerOptions":  {
"baseUrl":  "./",
"outDir":  "./dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap":  true,
"declaration":  false,
"module":  "esnext",  // add this line**
"moduleResolution":  "node",
"emitDecoratorMetadata":  true,
"experimentalDecorators":  true,
"importHelpers":  true,
"target":  "es2015",
"typeRoots":  [
"node_modules/@types"
],
"lib":  ["es2018","dom"]
  }
}
```

Note:

> Also make sure to check tsconfig.app.json dont have module and target config something like this**

```js
{
"extends": "./tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
"outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
"types": []
},
"include": [
"src/**/*.ts"
],
"exclude": [
"src/test.ts",
"src/**/*.spec.ts"
 ]
}
```

Note: ** below case only for angular material if you are using angular material then you have to import specific imports like below i have small list
————————————————————————
*_ErrorMessage:_*
***Angular material not found***

*_— Solution_*

```js
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatNativeDateModule, MatOptionModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatNativeDateModule,} from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

======================================================

***Update angular project using below cods***

> ng update
>   ng update @angular/core

======================================================
If you get these error which i mentioned below then only you have to configure your **tsconfig.app.json** accordingly

> Error message:

***the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.***
***Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.***

— **tsconfig.app.json**

```js
{
"extends": "../tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
"outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
// "module": "es2015",
"types": []
},
"exclude": [
"test.ts",
"**/*.spec.ts",
" ../../environments/*.ts"
 ],
}
```

___ in some project this file will be like —> **tsconfig.app.json**

```js
{
"extends": "./tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
"outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
"types": []
},
"files": [
"src/main.ts",
"src/polyfills.ts"
],
"include": [
"src/**/*.ts"
],
"exclude": [
"src/test.ts",
"src/**/*.spec.ts",
"**/*.spec.ts",
"src/././environments/*.ts"
]
}
```